# Разбиение списка списков на несколько

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, матрицы, список

Даны два списка

```
a=[
    [1,12,13,15,160,170,200],
    [1,12,13,15,160,170,200]
]
```

и

```
b=[
    [3,20,200],
    [5,50,250]
].
```

Необходимо разбить первый список на группы из второго списка по принципу

```
[
    [
        [1],
        [12,13,15],
        [160,170,200]
    ],
    [
        [1],
        [12,13,15],
        [160,170,200]
    ]
].
```

Т.е. числа из первого списка, должны попадать в интервалы из второго.

Comment: Списки всегда отсортированы?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы расписать интервалы? Хочется посмотреть на крайние значения и на то, в какой промежуток их включать.

Comment: Вы как-то очень криво пример подобрали, что, если b=[3,12,13,20,30,190,210]? Вот в таком случае, вроде бы, все крайние ситуации проявятся и можно понять логику будет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def hist(arr, bins):
    arr = pd.Series(arr)
    bins = [-np.inf] + list(bins)
    res = arr.groupby(pd.cut(arr, bins=bins)).apply(list)
    return res
```

примеры:

```
In [139]: hist(a[0], b[0])
Out[139]:
(-inf, 3.0]                  [1]
(3.0, 20.0]         [12, 13, 15]
(20.0, 200.0]    [160, 170, 200]
dtype: object

In [140]: hist(a[1], b[1])
Out[140]:
(-inf, 5.0]                  [1]
(5.0, 50.0]         [12, 13, 15]
(50.0, 250.0]    [160, 170, 200]
dtype: object
```

результаты в виде списка:

```
In [141]: list(hist(a[1], b[1]))
Out[141]: [[1], [12, 13, 15], [160, 170, 200]]

In [142]: [list(hist(i,j)) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[142]: [[[1], [12, 13, 15], [160, 170, 200]], [[1], [12, 13, 15], [160, 170, 200]]]
```